# Only port working with mod_proxy is 8009. Trying to use with tomcat and httpd/

Tags: apache, tomcat, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I am trying to use mod_proxy with httpd and tomcat. If I leave Tomcat ajp to run on 8009 in the server.xml of tomcat and in the httpd.conf of Apache httpd, everything works great, but once I change it to anything else and restart them both it does not work. I tried 8109,8209 and 8019, but the only thing that works is 8009.

Below is my setup that works:

```
<Proxy balancer://testcluster stickysession=JSESSIONID>
BalancerMember ajp://127.0.0.1:8009 min=10 max=100 route=node2 loadfactor=1
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /examples balancer://testcluster/examples

<Location /balancer-manager>
SetHandler balancer-manager
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Balancer Manager"
AuthUserFile "/etc/httpd/conf/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
</Location>
```

If I change the port to anything in here, and the server.xml of Tomcat it does not work, but I can telnet the port so I know its up.

Below are the other libs settings I have:

```
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so

#LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
#LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so


#LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
LoadModule suexec_module modules/mod_suexec.so
LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
```

Here is a link to the httpd.con file:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0UnSMAKoW5tZy0wOERjUjRhaXM/edit

Here is a link to the server.xml file:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0UnSMAKoW5tZGdiUkRZQ0hlWm8/edit

Comment: Can you post the server.xml and http.conf files that do not work so we can look for errors or causes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a issue with Scientific Linux release 6.2 I had to tell it to stop blocking the port by doing the following command

setenforce 0

it works then.